# Python 2D list when unknown number of elements

Tags: python, list, 2d

I undertook some Java programming many moons ago but am trying to now pickup the Python language.

I am trying to create a program where the user is constantly asked for 4 inputs (Firstname, Surname, Age, Gender) until they type 'END' at which point the program continues.

I am trying to use this code to teach some young learners and so although I appreciate there are more efficient ways I am looking for an easy to understand method which might build upon the knowledge of basic 1D lists they already have.

I am struggling to find how to have the 2D list setup and utilised.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: There are no 2D lists in python. But you can append lists (of different length) to a list. Can you show us your code that didn't solve your question?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny wouldn't that make it kinda a 2D list (or array? which seems to fit the dimension thing better as a term)? also I don't exactly understand what is asked. Should the user always input all 4 parameters? what if they don't and type "END"? It would be great if sample input and output were provided

Answer (score 0):

You can append lists to other lists in python.
Then you have something like a 2D list.

```
>>> x = []
>>> x.append(["Hello", "World"])
>>> x.append(["1", "2"])
>>> x
[['Hello', 'World'], ['1', '2']]
```

Maybe this code snippet helps:

```
names = []
while True:
  temp_list = []
  # Add your input methods here and append to temp_list
  temp_list.append(input("name"))

  names.append(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion probably makes the most sense for this problem. I also think storing the data in a dictionary makes more sense than a list but here is a pretty simple solution using lists:

```
from typing import List
def input_data(result=None) -> List[list]: # create a function with result set to None
    if result == None: # one first run when result is None create an empty list
        result = [] # empty list
    data = input('Enter the first name, surname, age and gender seperated by pipe: ') # input string
    if data.lower() == 'end': # if the string is equal to end then pass
        pass
    else:
        data = data.split('|')
        if len(data) != 4: # raise a value error to make sure you enter the correct number of items in the list
            raise ValueError(f'Input data must have a length of 4. Current length of data is {len(data)}: {data}')
        result.append(data) # append data to the result 
        input_data(result=result) # call the function again
    return result

lst_of_data = input_data()
print(lst_of_data)

# Enter the first name, surname, age and gender seperated by pipe:  john|doe|26|m
# Enter the first name, surname, age and gender seperated by pipe:  jane|doe|28|f
# Enter the first name, surname, age and gender seperated by pipe:  end
# [['john', 'doe', '26', 'm'], ['jane', 'doe', '28', 'f']]
```

Here is the same solution but with a dictionary

```
def input_data(result=None) -> dict: # create a function with result set to None
    if result == None: # one first run when result is None create an empty dict
        result = {'First Name': [], 'Surname': [], 'Age': [], 'Gender': []} # empty dict
    data = input('Enter the first name, surname, age and gender seperated by pipe: ') # input string
    if data.lower() == 'end': # if the string is equal to end then pass
        pass
    else:
        data = data.split('|')
        if len(data) != 4: # raise a value error to make sure you enter the correct number of items in the list
            raise ValueError(f'Input data must have a length of 4. Current length of data is {len(data)}: {data}')
        result['First Name'].append(data[0])
        result['Surname'].append(data[1])
        result['Age'].append(data[2])
        result['Gender'].append(data[3])
        input_data(result=result) # call the function again
    return result

dict_of_data = input_data()
print(dict_of_data)

# Enter the first name, surname, age and gender seperated by pipe:  john|doe|26|m
# Enter the first name, surname, age and gender seperated by pipe:  jane|doe|28|f
# Enter the first name, surname, age and gender seperated by pipe:  end
# {'First Name': ['john', 'jane'], 'Surname': ['doe', 'doe'], 'Age': ['26', '28'], 'Gender': ['m', 'f']}
```